# How to differ changing text of child class based on parent class in javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html

I try to set value and text of my child classes after clicking on one of two buttons in my html code

```js
$(".fce-pool-for > .fce-pool-bar").val($('.fce-pool-bar').val(Math.round(resultFor)));
$(".fce-pool-for > .fce-pool-percentage").text($('.fce-pool-percentage').text((Math.round(resultFor).toString()) + "%"));

$(".fce-pool-against > .fce-pool-bar").val($('.fce-pool-bar').val(Math.round(resultAgainst)));
$(".fce-pool-against > .fce-pool-percentage").text($('.fce-pool-percentage').text((Math.round(resultAgainst).toString()) + "%"));
```

```html
<div class="fce-pool-against">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">
      <p class="fce-pool-title">
        <?php the_sub_field('vote_against_title')?>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <progress class="fce-pool-bar" max="100" value="0"></progress>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <p class="fce-pool-percentage">0 %</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 offset-1">
      <a href="" class="fce-pool-button btn-primary" id="against_more">Less</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p>
    <?php the_sub_field('vote_against_note')?>
  </p>

</div>

<div class="fce-pool-for">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">
      <span class="fce-pool-title"><?php the_sub_field('vote_for_title')?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <progress class="fce-pool-bar" max="100" value="0"></progress>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <p class="fce-pool-percentage">0 %</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 offset-1">
      <a href="" class="fce-pool-button btn-success" id="more">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>
    <?php the_sub_field('vote_for_note')?>
  </p>
</div>
```

But do not know **how to set values when parent class is different**... please someone has an advice how to do that ???

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking. Please edit the question with more specifics

Comment: as you can see, I use <progress class="fce-pool-bar" max="100" value="0"></progress> and   <p class="fce-pool-percentage">0 %</p> on making pool statistics and would like to set value for bar and text for p element in similar way like this:  $('.fce-pool-bar').val(Math.round(resultFor));
        $('.fce-pool-percentage').text((Math.round(resultFor).toString()) + "%"); ... but I need to set different values for classes when they are under parent classs 'for' and parent class 'against'.... and i do not know how to catch content based on parent class

Comment: @charlietfl Seems clear to me at this point in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you get the `resultFor` and `resultAgainst` value from so I put an example of that in there, using the commented out functions.

Note the key to your question is "what was clicked, from where".  To do that, I attached an event handler to the pools `'.fce-pool-against, .fce-pool-for'`, targeting the buttons within that> `'.fce-pool-button'` as in:

```
$('.fce-pool-against, .fce-pool-for').on('click', '.fce-pool-button',
```

Then, inside the function I use the attached pool (the `delegateTarget`) and find stuff inside that during the click event handler function execution.

```
let pool = $(event.delegateTarget);
```

Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/

Perhaps a better solution is to use a data attribute in each pool, so I put an example of that in there, this makes the code much more generic, and we can attach a button click handler to each pool and then use that, finding the elements we need in each pool when clicked.

Separate thing snippet

```js
let resultFor = 20;
let resultAgainst = 13;

$('.fce-pool-for').on('click', '.fce-pool-button', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let pool = $(event.delegateTarget);
  let resultValue = Math.round(resultFor);
  pool.find('.fce-pool-percentage').text( resultValue + " %");
  pool.find('.fce-pool-bar').val(resultValue);
});

$('.fce-pool-against').on('click', '.fce-pool-button', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let pool = $(event.delegateTarget);
  let resultValue = Math.round(resultAgainst);
  pool.find('.fce-pool-percentage').text( resultValue + " %");
  pool.find('.fce-pool-bar').val(resultValue);
});
```

Use the data property/attribute to do something more generic:

```js
$('.fce-pool-against, .fce-pool-for').on('click', '.fce-pool-button', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // keep link from executing
  let pool = $(event.delegateTarget); // the pool
  let votes = pool.data('votes'); // data from the pool
  votes = votes + 1;
  // store new value
  pool.data('votes', votes);
  // update the percent and display
  $('.fce-pool-button').trigger('showvalues');
});
$('.fce-pool-against, .fce-pool-for')
  .on('showvalues', '.fce-pool-button', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // keep link from executing
    let pool = $(event.delegateTarget); // the pool
    let votes = pool.data('votes'); // data from the pool
    let totalVotes = 0;
    $('.fce-pool-button').each(function(e) {
      totalVotes = totalVotes + $(this).closest('.fce-pool').data('votes');
    });
    let percent = (votes / totalVotes) * 100;
    //console.log(totalVotes, votes, percent);
    let resultValue = Math.round(percent);
    // find the elements in our pool, set them
    pool.find('.fce-pool-percentage').text(resultValue + " %");
    pool.find('.fce-pool-bar').val(resultValue);
    pool.find('.votes-display').text(votes);
  })
  .find('.fce-pool-button')
  .trigger('showvalues'); // trigger initial display
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="fce-pool fce-pool-against" data-votes="25">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">
      <span class="fce-pool-title">
        Against
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <progress class="fce-pool-bar" max="100" value="0"></progress>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <p class="fce-pool-percentage">0 %</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 offset-1">
      <a href="" class="fce-pool-button btn-primary" id="against_more">Less</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>
    Against Votes: <span class="votes-display"></span>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="fce-pool fce-pool-for" data-votes="43">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">
      <span class="fce-pool-title">For</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <progress class="fce-pool-bar" max="100" value="0"></progress>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <p class="fce-pool-percentage">0 %</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 offset-1">
      <a href="" class="fce-pool-button btn-success" id="more">More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>
    For Votes: <span class="votes-display"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Note I removed the php replacing it with text since it had nothing to do with the question.

Comment: learned something new...never even knew about delegateTarget...handy

Comment: votesFor represents number of clicks on More button and votesAgainst represents number of clicks on Less button... you have great solution :) ofcourse. I need to influence both progress bars and set value after calculating and changing values of votesFor and votesAgainst :) hopefully it would not be big problem to solve.. but your solution will be great example for me :) definitely

Comment: I added ability to increment based on clicks and display initial and on each update via a click

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to be able to isolate the parent class of whichever `fce-pool-button` is clicked.

Give the `fce-pool-against` and `fce-pool-for` parents a common class like `fce-pool` along with the classes they already have.

Then you can isolate the parent `fce-pool` class by traversing to `closest('.fce-pool')` and use `find()` within that parent to look for instance specific elements like the `<progress>`.

You can also use `is()` to determine whether it is `for` or `against` pool so you know how to manage the data for that instance

```
$('.fce-pool-button').click(function(event){
  // "this" is the button that was clicked
   var $pool = $(this).closest('.fce-pool'),
       // find the progess element in current instance
       $progress = $pool.find('progress.fce-pool-bar'),
       // set boolean to know which type it is 
       isForPool = $pool.is('.fce-pool-for');// true/false 

   // now use logic similar to
   $progress.val( isForPool ? resultFor : resultAgainst)

})
```

Comment: This is one way to get the parent "pool" markup, nothing wrong with this up to that point.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss thank you for your advice, it looks really helpful, but I can`t use your solution, cause my event is in $(document).ready(function () {} .. how to implement your example in that? .on('click', '.fce-pool-button', function(event) is not working, unfortunatelly

Comment: @MatusVrsansky  Are you referencing this answer or the one I put forth?  I only made a comment on this one.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss  I apologize, I had to change parameter, but it is working already :) now I need to  find solution how to draw result for both progress bars without clicking on button, in "window.onload" function. I do not know, how to separate it, when is forLoop . draw 20% and when is AgainstLoop, draw 40%. But that is my problem and your solution helped me so much , THANK YOU !!!